# How do I optimise displaying time durations in a human-readable way?

Tags: mysql, perl

I want to implement a functionality for my project. It's very similar to a feature on Stack Overflow where user post requests and gets responses. Here on Stack Overflow we see post marked as 4 seconds ago, 22 seconds ago, 1 minute ago, 5 minutes ago etc. I want to implement the same.

I am storing the request posted time in a timestamp variable in MySQL, then subtracting `NOW() - stored_time` to get the seconds. Then writing some logic, like

- if less than 60 seconds, display 60 seconds ago
- if difference in between 60 to 3600, display in minutes

and so on. This long logic is written in Perl. I want to avoid that. Is there any good way to achieve the same thing? I am open to change the MySQL table and data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the datestamps as [DateTime](http://p3rl.org/DateTime) objects. You don't show any details of your database, so I have to skip that step in my answer.

```
use DateTime qw();
use DateTime::Format::Human::Duration qw();

for my $seconds (555, 5555, 555555, 5555555) {
    my $now = DateTime->now;
    my $before = $now->clone->subtract(seconds => $seconds);
    my $formatted = DateTime::Format::Human::Duration
        ->new->format_duration($before - $now);
    $formatted =~ s/(?:,| and).*//;
    print "about $formatted ago\n";
}

# about 9 minutes ago
# about 1 hour ago
# about 6 days ago
# about 2 months ago
```

Comment: Thanks daxim. Now I am able to get the time in human readable form. There is one minor issue. Its displaying as 24 minutes and 7 seconds ago -  I just want to display 24 minutes. or for 1 week, 1 day, 21 hours, 55 minutes, and 52 seconds ago, I just want 1 week. How can i achieve that?

Comment: `DateTime::Format::Human::Duration` unfortunately does not expose that functionality, you only get a string with full details. You need to cut off what you don't want by yourself. See the edited code above.

Answer (score 2):

Send number of elapsed seconds to client and convert it to human-readable text in JavaScript.

Comment: Hi, Can you explain little bit about it? How this will help me?

Comment: You will do only minimal required and very fast work server side, moving expensive number to human text conversion to client side, taking advantage of client's computational power.